# Functions on irreducible invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a vector space  which is a direct sum of two of its subspaces. I believe that then the dimensions of the subsets have to be smaller than that of the set they make up:

$$V=V_1\oplus V_2$$

then $\dim V_1 < \dim V$ and $\dim V = \dim V_1 + \dim V_2$.

If this is correct then, how should I understand the following:

Let $F:V\to V$, we call $V_1$ invariant  if $F$ displays $V_1\to V_1$. But how can that be, if $F$ requires vectors from $V$ that is with a certain dimension?

One idea that I can imagine in say $\mathcal{R}^n$ is that if $\mathcal{R}^n=\mathcal{R}^{n_1}\oplus \mathcal{R}^{n_2}$ such that $n_1+n_2=n$, then F is invariant on say $\mathcal{R}^{n_1}$ if it displays all vectors that are like $(x_1,\ldots,x_{n_1},0,\ldots,0)\to (y_1,\ldots,y_{n_1},0,\ldots,0)$ and on $\mathcal{R}^{n_2}$ if it displays $(0,\ldots,0,x_{n_1+1},\ldots,x_{n_2})\to (0,\ldots,0,y_{n_1+1},\ldots,y_{n_2})$.

But I am still not comfortable saying that we reduce $F$ to say $V_1$ because if we are talking about acting on $V_1$, I think we need to talk about a different function which, however, displays $n_1$ tuples $V_1$ on $n_1$ tuples in $V_1$ as suggested above.

Can someone please clarify this?

Comment: Do you mean "vector space which is the direct sum of two of its subspaces"? I don't understand "displays". Do you just mean $F(V_1)\subseteq V_1$? You need to check your understanding of "dimension": it is a property of spaces, not of vectors. You are right that if $F(V_1)\subseteq V_1$ then the map $g:V_1\to V_1$ by $x\mapsto F(x)$ is not really the map $F$. But it's a well known useful abuse of notation.

Comment: Yes, the spaces are vector spaces. By display, I mean probably map or act, i am not sure of english terminology: basically, function "eats" vectors from one vector space and spits out vector from somewhere else, this is what I call display or act or map. I am sorry, if I somewhere mentioned word "dimension" in connection with a vector, what I meant was probably the word tuple ($n$ ordered elements representing a vector). Finally, I still do not understand the logic how I should understand the restriction to the subspace (how that "eating" of vectors in $V$ represents eating in $V_1$?

Comment: As $V_1\subseteq V$, we have that $x\in V_1$ implies $x\in V$ and so $F(x)$ makes perfect sense; then as $F(x)\in V_1$ by definition of "invariant under $F$", we have that $F$ has taken a vector in $V_1$ and given as output a vector of $V_1$. In your example note that it technically wrong as $\mathbb{R}^{n_1}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$: I think that mentally you are confusing the lengths of the tuples with dimension of the space.

Comment: The definition I am trying to understand is: "We call an invariant subspace $W$ irreducible with respect to $F$ if it cannot be written as a direct sum of its 2 invariant subspaces." Now, this should be correct according to my definition of direct sum $\mathcal{R}^2 = \mathcal{R}^1\oplus \mathcal{R}^1$ but at the same time you are saying that $\mathcal{R}^1$ is not a subspace of $\mathcal{R}^2$ but my definition of direct sum applies to subspaces $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ where $V_i$ are subspaces of $V$. So how can I reconcile this?

Comment: The vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the set of $1$-tuples. Your decomposition is into $V_1\oplus V_2$ where $V_1=\{(x,0) : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ which is NOT equal to $\mathbb{R}^1$, but is isomorphic to it.     $V_1$ is a one-dimensional space consisting of certain $2$-tuples.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$ in the direct sum $V=V_1\oplus V_2$ are not (strictly speaking) subsets of $V$, but can be understood as such by the means of isomorphism which I suggested in the case of $/mathcal{R}^n$?

Comment: No, quite the opposite.